# Get longest streak of consecutive weeks by group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

Currently I'm working with weekly data for different subjects, but it might have some long streaks without data, so, what I want to do, is to just keep the longest streak of consecutive weeks for every `id`. My data looks like this:

```
id    week
1      8
1      15
1      60
1      61
1      62
2      10
2      11
2      12
2      13
2      25
2      26
```

My expected output would be:

```
id    week
1      60
1      61
1      62
2      10
2      11
2      12
2      13
```

I got a bit close, trying to mark with a 1 when `week`==`week.shift()+1`. The problem is this approach doesn't mark the first occurrence in a streak, and also I can't filter the longest one:

```
df.loc[ (df['id'] == df['id'].shift())&(df['week'] == df['week'].shift()+1),'streak']=1
```

This, according to my example, would bring this:

```
id    week  streak
1      8     nan
1      15    nan
1      60    nan
1      61    1
1      62    1
2      10    nan
2      11    1
2      12    1
2      13    1
2      25    nan
2      26    1
```

Any ideas on how to achieve what I want?

Comment: you can have another column(streak1) by applying this: `week==week.shift(-1)-1`, this way you can identify the first one as well. you may need xor streak and streak1 for the final result

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['consec'] = df.groupby(['id',df['week'].diff(-1).ne(-1).shift().bfill().cumsum()]).transform('count')

df[df.groupby('id')['consec'].transform('max') == df.consec]
```

Output:

```
   id  week  consec
2   1    60       3
3   1    61       3
4   1    62       3
5   2    10       4
6   2    11       4
7   2    12       4
8   2    13       4
```

Comment: Woah, that's nice. Only problem is I got this error: `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 30, placement implies 1` , when running the first line. Do you know what could have happened?

Comment: Try to upgrade pandas first.

Comment: Just one small suggestion in your 2rd groupkey , I think using groupby to create it is more save .`df.groupby('id').week.apply(lambda x : x.diff().ne(1).cumsum())
`

Comment: Tried updating pandas and now I can't import it. Getting this error: `AttributeError: module 'numpy.core.umath' has no attribute 'divmod'`

Comment: Edit: updated numpy and now it's working. Now I'm getting `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 25, placement implies 1`

Comment: Also got this when trying @Wen-Ben 's option: `ValueError: transforms cannot produce aggregated results` 

Should I run `df['consec'] = df.groupby('id').t_semana.apply(lambda x : x.diff().ne(1).cumsum()).transform('count')` or `df['consec'] = df.groupby('id').t_semana.apply(lambda x : x.diff().ne(1).cumsum())` ?

Comment: After just selecting `id` and `week` in my dataframe the code works. Didn't think before that `groupby` might iteract in a bad way with the other columns. Thanks to both of you !

Answer (score 2):

Not as concise as @ScottBoston but I like this approach

```
def max_streak(s):
  a = s.values    # Let's deal with an array

  # I need to know where the differences are not `1`.
  # Also, because I plan to use `diff` again, I'll wrap
  # the boolean array with `True` to make things cleaner
  b = np.concatenate([[True], np.diff(a) != 1, [True]])

  # Tell the locations of the breaks in streak
  c = np.flatnonzero(b)

  # `diff` again tells me the length of the streaks
  d = np.diff(c)

  # `argmax` will tell me the location of the largest streak
  e = d.argmax()

  return c[e], d[e]

def make_thing(df):
  start, length = max_streak(df.week)
  return df.iloc[start:start + length].assign(consec=length)

pd.concat([
  make_thing(g) for _, g in df.groupby('id')    
])

   id  week  consec
2   1    60       3
3   1    61       3
4   1    62       3
5   2    10       4
6   2    11       4
7   2    12       4
8   2    13       4
```