# Return the length of the longest consecutive months by group in pandas

Tags: pandas

**df**

```
    id  date
0   a   202007
1   a   202008
2   a   202009
3   a   202010
4   a   202011
5   b   202011
6   c   202011
7   c   202012
8   c   202101
9   c   202102
10  d   202101
11  d   202102
12  d   202103
13  d   202105
14  e   202012
15  e   202101
16  e   202102
17  e   202104
18  e   202105
14  f   202012
15  f   202101
16  f   202103
17  f   202104
18  f   202105
```

The second column type is int.

**Expected**

```
a  5
b  1
c  4
d  3
e  3
f  3
```

**Try and Ref**

- Ref： [Get longest streak of consecutive weeks by group in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54698474/get-longest-streak-of-consecutive-weeks-by-group-in-pandas)

I refer above post but still could get the results.

Note: For each id, the value of date is unique.

Pandas version: 1.1.5

Comment: Super, `e` value is correct?

Comment: @jezrael I update it. It's 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert datetimes to month periods by [`Series.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html) and then to integers and then instead `transform` use [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) with `max` per first level, here `id`:

```
per = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m').dt.to_period('m').astype('int')
g = per.diff(-1).ne(-1).shift().bfill().cumsum()

df = df.groupby(['id',g]).size().max(level=0).reset_index(name='count')
print (df)
  id  count
0  a      5
1  b      1
2  c      4
3  d      3
4  e      3
5  f      3
```

For oldier pandas version is possible get attribute `n` from `MonthEnd object` if not missing value by custom function after `diff`:

```
f = lambda x: x.n if pd.notna(x) else None
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m').dt.to_period('m')
g = df['date'].diff(-1).apply(f).ne(-1).shift().bfill().cumsum()

df = df.groupby(['id',g]).size().max(level=0).reset_index(name='count')
print (df)
  id  count
0  a      5
1  b      1
2  c      4
3  d      3
4  e      3
5  f      3
```

Comment: Why the e value is not 3. '202012'; '202101','202102'

Comment: @Jack - You are right, answer was edited.

Comment: I got"TypeError: Passing PeriodDtype data is invalid. Use `data.to_timestamp()` instead." when I ran the first row.

Comment: @Jack - What is your pandas version?

Comment: Mine is 1.1.5 .

Comment: @Jack - Tested in pandas 1.2.3

Comment: Is there any method that can works under 1.1.5 because mine update runs slow.

Comment: @Jack - So for you failed `pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m').dt.to_period('m').astype('int')` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229812/discussion-between-jack-and-jezrael).